# Remove / overcome / exceed / overtake maximum characters limit of Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel as a primitive but very practical offline grid database. When needed, the Excel file is then uploaded and it populates a mySQL db.

Now I added the support to images by encoding them base64 and saving the string into a cell (mySQL will use the content of the cell to fill a BLOB record).

I would like to solve the case that Excel cells have a maximum length of 32,767 characters (it may happen that the result string of an image base64 encoded has more than 32,767 characters).

I tried to overcome this limit by setting custom cell validation using the 'data validation' option as follows

```
With Range("R3:R1000").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateTextLength, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="0", _
        Formula2:="3000000"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .ShowError = False
End With
```

But the cell content is still truncated at 32,767 characters. I did set the `TextBox` property `MaxLength` accordingly.

By the way, if I populate the TextBox with an image base64 encoded and then I copy/paste the string from the TextBox to a online base64 image decoder, the image is decoded perfectly. If I copy/paste that same string by getting the cell content, the image if truncated at 32,767 characters.

The issue happens when the content of the TextBox is copied into the cell. This confirms it is the 32,767 maximum length of the cell that should be overcome or removed.

Comment: I think you're stuck at that limit - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f . Maybe use two cells and concatenate them together in mySQL?

Comment: Uhmmm... that could be an idea. Still don't understand what the `text lenght` in the `data validation` menu is used for.

Comment: It limits the number of characters you can enter in a cell - I guess your code example will allow between 0 and the maximum characters allowed (so the same as not having validation).

Comment: Ok, fine. In the meanwhile I splitted the string >32,000 characters between multiples cells. I tested the result by copy/pasting the various 'segments' into an image decoder and it worked at the very first temptative! I will keep this solution, many thanks. (Thinking out-of-the-box at its best!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Darren (see comments above) the best and safest solution is to split the string into different cells.

The following code splits the string into parts with lenght < 32,000 characters. It add the parts to an array and then it writes the parts to the needed number of adjacent cells:

```
iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
col = 1

' Get string from txtEncodedImage text input
sArray = SplitStr(txtEncodedImage.Value, 32000)

For i = LBound(sArray) To UBound(sArray)
    ws.Cells(iRow, col + i).Value = sArray(i)
Next i


Public Function SplitStr(ByVal str As String, ByVal numOfCharacters As Long) As String()
    Dim sArray() As String
    Dim nCount As Long
    Dim c As Long
    c = Len(str) \ numOfCharacters
    If c * numOfCharacters = Len(str) Then
        ReDim sArray(1 To c)
    Else
        ReDim sArray(1 To c + 1)
    End If
    For c = 1 To Len(str) Step numOfCharacters
        nCount = nCount + 1
        sArray(nCount) = Mid(str, c, numOfCharacters)
    Next
    SplitStr = sArray
End Function
```